# Expression of Klein-Gordon field in Heisenberg picture

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, fourier-transform, klein-gordon-equation

In Schrodinger picture, the scalar field is
$$
\phi(\vec{x}) = \int \frac{d^3 p}{2E(\vec{p})} \left( a(\vec{p}) e^{i\vec{p}\cdot\vec{x}} + a(\vec{p})^{\dagger} e^{-i\vec{p}\cdot\vec{x}} \right).    \tag{1}
$$
We change to the Heisenberg picture, we have
$$
\phi(x) = e^{iHt} \phi(\vec{x}) e^{-iHt} \quad (2)
$$
where $x=(t,\vec{x})$. For $a(\vec{p})$ or $a(\vec{p})^{\dagger}$, for example, we have
$$
e^{iHt} a(\vec{p}) e^{-iHt} = a(\vec{p}) e^{-iE(\vec{p})t} \quad (3)
$$
In Peskin and Schoroeder's book (Page:25), it gives exact expression for $\phi(x)$, i.e.,
$$
\phi(x) = \int \frac{d^3 p}{2E(\vec{p})} \left( a(\vec{p}) e^{ip\cdot x} + a(\vec{p})^{\dagger} e^{-ip\cdot x} \right) \quad (4)
$$
where $p$ and $x$ is four momentum vector and four position vector, respectively.

From the Eq.(1) and Eq.(2), we can see that $e^{\pm iHt}$ is outside of integral. In addition, $E$ is a function of $\vec{p}$, namely, $E=E(\vec{p})$. I think that in the book, it puts the Eq.(3) inside of integral. I can not understand why can we do this? From the Eq.(2), I think $e^{\pm iE(\vec{p})t}$ should be outside of the integral. Since $E$ is dependent on $\vec{p}$, if we put it inside of integral, does it affect the result of integral?

Answer (score 0):

One easy to deal with these difficulties is to just imagine the integral is discretized, then the measure even more clearly is just a c-number multiplying the annihilation and creation operators, $H$ commutes with a c-number (you can put identity with it, to be more clear), then you can move the factor inside.